# Error occured when apt-get update run

Tags: apt, 14.04, updates

I tried to run `sudo apt-get update` on Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.

And here is result:

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                                             

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                                             

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                                             

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease            

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease            


W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gilir/lubuntu/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kilian/f.lux/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/shutter/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-on-rails/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/cassou/emacs/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/diesch/testing/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gilir/lubuntu/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kilian/f.lux/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/shutter/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-on-rails/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.canonical.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::1b). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::1b 80]

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Here is output after run `find /etc/apt -name '*.list' -exec bash -c 'echo -e "\n$1\n"; cat -n "$1"' _ '{}' \;`:

```
    /etc/apt/sources_20140408-22:53:08/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java-trusty.list

     1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
     2  # deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main

/etc/apt/sources_20140408-22:53:08/sources.list.d/opera.list

     1  # This file makes sure that Opera Browser is kept up-to-date
     2  # as part of regular system upgrades
     3
     4  deb http://deb.opera.com/opera/ stable non-free #Opera Browser (final releases)
     5
     6
     7

/etc/apt/sources_20140408-22:53:08/sources.list.d/chris-lea-node_js-trusty.list

     1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu trusty main
     2  # deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu trusty main

/etc/apt/sources_20140408-22:53:08/sources.list.d/shutter-ppa-trusty.list

     1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/shutter/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
     2  # deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/shutter/ppa/ubuntu trusty main

/etc/apt/sources_20140408-22:53:08/sources.list.d/tualatrix-ppa-trusty.list

     1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
     2  # deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu trusty main

/etc/apt/sources_20140408-22:53:08/sources.list.d/webupd8team-sublime-text-3-trusty.list

     1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu trusty main
     2  # deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu trusty main

/etc/apt/sources_20140408-22:53:08/sources.list.d/cassou-emacs-trusty.list

     1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/cassou/emacs/ubuntu trusty main
     2  # deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/cassou/emacs/ubuntu trusty main

/etc/apt/sources_20140408-22:53:08/sources.list.d/gilir-lubuntu-trusty.list

     1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gilir/lubuntu/ubuntu trusty main
     2  # deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/gilir/lubuntu/ubuntu trusty main

/etc/apt/sources_20140408-22:53:08/sources.list.d/private-ppa.launchpad.net_commercial-ppa-uploaders_intellij-idea-ce_ubuntu.list

     1  deb https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/intellij-idea-ce/ubuntu precise main #Added by software-center; credentials stored in /etc/apt/auth.conf

/etc/apt/sources_20140408-22:53:08/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list

     1  ### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
     2  # You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
     3  deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main

/etc/apt/sources_20140408-22:53:08/sources.list.d/diesch-testing-trusty.list

     1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/diesch/testing/ubuntu trusty main
     2  # deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/diesch/testing/ubuntu trusty main

/etc/apt/sources_20140408-22:53:08/sources.list.d/fossfreedom-packagefixes-trusty.list

     1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu trusty main
     2  # deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu trusty main

/etc/apt/sources_20140408-22:53:08/sources.list

     1  # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-GNOME 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20140326.1)]/ trusty main multiverse restricted universe
     2
     3  # See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
     4  # newer versions of the distribution.
     5  deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
     6  deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
     7
     8  ## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
     9  ## distribution.
    10  deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
    11  deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
    12
    13  ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
    14  ## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
    15  ## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
    23  ## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
    24  ## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
    25  ## security team.
    26  deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
    27  deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
    28  deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
    29  deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
    30
    31  ## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
    32  ## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
    33  ## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
    34  ## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
    35  ## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
    36  deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    37  deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    38
    39  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
    40  deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
    41  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
    42  deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
    43  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
    44  deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
    45
    46  ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
    47  ## 'partner' repository.
    48  ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
    49  ## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
    50  # deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
    51  # deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
    52
    53  ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
    54  ## developers who want to ship their latest software.
    55  deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
    56  deb http://archive.canonical.com/ trusty partner
    57  # deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ trusty partner
    58  deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java-trusty.list

     1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
     2  # deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list

     1  # This file makes sure that Opera Browser is kept up-to-date
     2  # as part of regular system upgrades
     3
     4  deb http://deb.opera.com/opera/ stable non-free #Opera Browser (final releases)
     5
     6
     7

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/typesafe-apt.list

     1  # Typesafe repository.
     2  deb http://apt.typesafe.com/ unicorn main # Typesafe "unicorn" releases.

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/chris-lea-node_js-trusty.list

     1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu trusty main
     2  # deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu trusty main
     3  # deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu trusty main

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kilian-f_lux-trusty.list

     1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kilian/f.lux/ubuntu trusty main
     2  # deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/kilian/f.lux/ubuntu trusty main

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-on-rails-ppa-trusty.list

     1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-on-rails/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
     2  # deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-on-rails/ppa/ubuntu trusty main

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/shutter-ppa-trusty.list

     1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/shutter/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
     2  # deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/shutter/ppa/ubuntu trusty main

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/tualatrix-ppa-trusty.list

     1  # deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
     2  # deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu trusty main

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-sublime-text-3-trusty.list

     1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu trusty main
     2  # deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu trusty main

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassou-emacs-trusty.list

     1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/cassou/emacs/ubuntu trusty main
     2  # deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/cassou/emacs/ubuntu trusty main

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gilir-lubuntu-trusty.list

     1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gilir/lubuntu/ubuntu trusty main
     2  # deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/gilir/lubuntu/ubuntu trusty main

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/private-ppa.launchpad.net_commercial-ppa-uploaders_intellij-idea-ce_ubuntu.list

     1  deb https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/intellij-idea-ce/ubuntu precise main #Added by software-center; credentials stored in /etc/apt/auth.conf

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list

     1  ### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
     2  # You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
     3  deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/diesch-testing-trusty.list

     1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/diesch/testing/ubuntu trusty main
     2  # deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/diesch/testing/ubuntu trusty main

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fossfreedom-packagefixes-trusty.list

     1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu trusty main
     2  # deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu trusty main

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongo.list

     1  ##10gen package location
     2   
     3  deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen

/etc/apt/sources.list
    20
    21  ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
    22  ## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
    23  ## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
    24  ## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
    25  ## security team.
    26  deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
    27  deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
    28  deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
    29  deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
    30
    31  ## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
    32  ## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
    33  ## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
    34  ## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
    35  ## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
    36  deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    37  deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    38
    39  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
    40  deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
    41  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
    42  deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
    43  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
    44  deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
    45
    46  ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
    47  ## 'partner' repository.
    48  ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
    49  ## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
    50  # deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
    51  # deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
    52
    53  ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
    54  ## developers who want to ship their latest software.
    55  deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
    56  deb http://archive.canonical.com/ trusty partner
    57  # deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ trusty partner
    58  deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

***How to solve this trouble?***

Comment: Try after changing download server from Software & Updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried changing the server from which Ubuntu downloads updates.

Here's how you do it. Follow next steps:

> Software's & Updates → Ubuntu Software (tab) → Download from:
>
> Change the server to any other available one.

Comment: It works. But why the best server for my location is failing?

Comment: Umm maybe your local server is down for some reason. Try to reconnect to your server after  a few days. I am guessing here

Comment: Bits of infrastructure have been down, launchpad was one of them. Should be fine later