# can't download and install updates on ubuntu 14.04.1 lts

Tags: 14.04, updates

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS in my laptop. I am new to this OS, I previously used windows 8.1,  so I don’t know much. I am having problem with updating. I cannot install and update softwares from software update. So please help me. I have also tried to update through terminal using,

```
sudo apt-get update
```

But it says.....

```
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                  
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                
Unable to connect to extras.ubuntu.com:http:
0% [Connecting to in.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.92.200)] [Connecting to securit
```

I want some suggestions.

Comment: Can we assume your sure your internet connection is working? You can surf the web? I would check to see if your network drivers are all functioning properly. But, I'm a n00b, too. I've encountered problems with network drivers, or lack thereof, clustering installs.

Comment: can you connect to (ping?) 91.189.92.200?

Comment: Have a look at this thread http://askubuntu.com/questions/483565/error-occured-when-apt-get-update-run.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to try,

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

and see what happens. It can be a quick fix sometimes.

Comment: it's not working..